# How can I change the default website connection timeout in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, networking, connection, timeout

I want to change the default timeout in Chrome. In Firefox I can set the value of `network.http.connection-timeout` in `about:config` - but how can I do that in Chrome?

Comment: In case anyone comes here wondering how to simulate XHR connection errors while developing web apps, you can use device mode to do so.

Comment: **Note** that newer versions of Firefox no longer use [that configuration](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.connect.timeout). It also uses the system-level configuration which can be changed as mentioned in [NOSUKE's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1110259/117986).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**You can't**. Google has been ignoring requests to implement this feature for [over six years](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gb_bZzmCnm4), so I wouldn't hold your breath.

Comment: WOW. That is why Chrome should not be the dominant Browser. Just because Google does not like something, they should not be able to prevent it.

Comment: @Blackbam I can't and won't agree with you. If anything they are pushing vendors and everyone else to deliver better user experiences. There is no need to wait for a page to load above a certain threshold time. If the server can't handle the requests, it's better to kill active pending request, so the server doesn't die of overload.

Comment: @Rumplin A user should have the power to change it. You can not deliver pages which load like super long. But still you should be able to configure a tool to certain needs.

Comment: Ironically, this is the **most** annoying (for me) on https://drive.google.com

Comment: @Rumplin Looking at weight and performance of Google services, and how memory-hungry the Chrome itself, and how they ignore all the negative feedback people give, and how they discriminate other browsers based on their User-Agent (Opera and Vivaldi in particular), and all the lack of configurability, etc., etc., they clearly _don't_ care about real user experience, but only what _they_ think user experience is about! Speaking of timeouts, in my recent tests I haven't got any connection or response timeouts at all for 15+ minutes.

Answer (score 16):

It's hopeless. They just won't do anything about enabling users to change Chrome's timeout settings. But you could switch to any of four other Gecko-based browsers in common use that have no timeout problems. Or you could start using one of the Mozilla-based browsers.

Comment: I was tempted to mark this as "not an answer", but I realized that you are suggesting an alternative solution. I would suggest editing it and indicating that so others aren't tempted to downvote or flag it.

Comment: Mozilla is Gecko based....  WebKit / Blink (Google's WebKit fork) is probably what you meant?

Answer (score 5):

I dealt with this issue by editing the registry. I think the registry affects not only IE but also Chrome in Windows 10.
I tried extend time-out. then I can extend it and max time-out is about 7Hrs in my case.

Reference: [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813827)

Click Start or press <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to get Run box, type `regedit`, and then click OK.

Locate and then click the following key in the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\InternetSettings
```

On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.

Type `KeepAliveTimeout`, and then press Enter.

On the Edit menu, click Modify.

Type the appropriate time-out value (in milliseconds), and then click OK. For example, to set the time-out value to two minutes, type `120000`.

Make another DWORD value `ServerInfoTimeout` and set it to the same value.

Restart machine.

Comment: As of today, this doesn't seem to work